# Remove or reinstall broken package installation

Tags: fedora, rpm, dnf

I tried to install "variety" manually via a downloaded rpm from http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/sourceforge/p/po/postinstaller/fedora/releases/23/x86_64/variety-0.5.5-1.fc23.noarch.html

The installation failed and now I would like to fix it. However, using simple `dnf` commands that came to mind do not allow to install, reinstall or remove the package:

```
✘ foo@bar > ~/Downloads > sudo dnf reinstall ./variety-0.5.5-1.fc23.noarch.rpm 
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:05:14 ago on Tue Feb 16 07:51:51 2016.
Package variety-0.5.5-1.fc23.noarch not installed, cannot reinstall it.
Error: Nothing to do.


 ✘ foo@bar > ~/Downloads > sudo dnf install ./variety-0.5.5-1.fc23.noarch.rpm  
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:05:19 ago on Tue Feb 16 07:51:51 2016.
Dependencies resolved.
========================================================================================================================
 Package                   Arch                     Version                        Repository                      Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 variety                   noarch                   0.5.5-1.fc23                   @commandline                   778 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 778 k
Installed size: 2.5 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction check error:
  package variety-0.5.5-1.fc23.noarch is already installed

Error Summary
-------------


 ✘ foor@bar > ~/Downloads > sudo dnf remove variety                              
No match for argument: variety
Error: No packages marked for removal.
```

How can I fix this? Should I manually delete the package contents?

Comment: "rpm -Uvh --force ./variety-0.5.5-1.fc23.noarch.rpm" works for you?